# How to encode the PEM file's content to base64 with python

Tags: python, base64

I have a PEM file and use the below command to encode its content to base64 manually

```
cat hello.pem | base64
```

How can I do the same thing with Python? I used base64 lib, but didn't get the same string as I got by the above command.

```
base64.b64encode(pem_file_content)
```

The content file is a string like below

```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```

It is generated by using this command

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
```

Basically I just read the content file and convert it to string. My task is now want to encode this string to base64.

- Output using command:

  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
- Output using python with base64

  b'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'

Comment: can you give an example of your input and the two different outputs?

Comment: @jps Hi, I just updated my question.

Comment: the generated key is already in base64 format. What's the purpose of encoding it again?

Comment: use https://www.base64decode.org/ to see the difference. The first command creates a base64 of formatted content (with linebreaks) the second on has just a long string.

Comment: @jps the first output is done by using command manually. Now I want to do it automatically using Python script. Basically people just provide the pem file and the script encode to base64 automatically for them. The original content of the pem file is not encoded in base64 btw.

Comment: The `b'...'` sigil indicates that what you have is a sequence of `bytes`. You can convert it to a string (if that's what you are asking) by doing `.encode('ascii')`

Comment: what you show above under *The content file is a string like below* is base64. Of course the header and trailer parts `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` are not.

Comment: @tripleee I got this error
'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: @jps not sure about that. That is generated from openssl rsakey command. Btw I still need to encode those values to base64.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `decode` obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using codecs - the built-in module

```
codecs.decode(bytes_content)
```

This will convert the bytes to string by removing the b'' and keep only encoded string.